# addError method doesn't work for jqueryvalidation

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, axios

I'm trying to use jqueryvalidation for my form validation, here is its document: http://www.runningcoder.org/jqueryvalidation/

My HTML code, this is my form:

```html
<form action="javascript:;" method="post" id="VerLogin">
    <div class="form-group mb-4">
        <input id="email" name="email" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email"
               data-validation="[NOTEMPTY]"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group mb-4">
        <input id="password" name="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Şifre"
               data-validation="[NOTEMPTY]"/>
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-primary text-center w-100" type="submit">
        <strong>Giriş Yap</strong>
    </button>
</form>
```

My Javascript code, form is coming here when it's submitted:

```js
$('#VerLogin').validate({
    submit: {
        settings: {
            inputContainer: '.form-group',
            errorListClass: 'form-control-error-list',
            errorClass: 'has-danger',
        },
        callback: {
            onSubmit: function (formData) {
                axios.post('/panel/api/verlogin', $(formData).serialize()).then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response.data);
                    switch (response.data.STATUS) {
                        case 'ERR_USERNAME_TAKEN':
                            $('#VerLogin').addError(response.data.ERR);
                            break;

                        case 'SUCC':
                            $('#VerLogin').addError(response.data.ERR);
                            break;
                    }
                })
            }
        },
    },
    debug: true
})
```

My PHP code, it comes after javascript axios.post()

```php
switch (UrlRead(3)) {
    case 'verlogin':
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];

        if ($email == "deneme@deneme.com") {
            $Return['STATUS'] = "ERR_USERNAME_TAKEN";
            $Return['ERR'] = array(
                'email' => 'Username is Taken.'
            );
        } else {
            $Return['STATUS'] = "SUCC";
            $Return['ERR'] = array(
                'email' => 'Username is available.'
            );
        }
        break;
}
echo json_encode($Return, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

After here it returns to javascript, it enters into cases of 'ERR_USERNAME_TAKEN' and 'SUCC', i tested it with console.log, but addError method doesn't work. Debug doesn't work also. Here is my console:

[image: my console]

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `status` envelope is obscuring the result. `addError` is expecting to see the input element name in the root of the argument object

```
$("#VerLogin").addError({
    "email": "Email is taken"
});
```

So, maybe try this?

```
if ($email == "deneme@deneme.com") {
            $Return = array(
                'email' => 'Username is Taken.',
                'STATUS' => "ERR_USERNAME_TAKEN"
            );
        }
```

Comment: I tried typing $("#VerLogin").addError({"email": "Email is taken"}); by hand, it didn't work either, addError method is the problem here. Also, status envelope works as intented, as you can see it detects STATUS and enters in cases, but thank you.